# How do I write a bash script to restart a service if it dies?

Tags: bash, scripting, daemon

I have a program that runs as a daemon, using the C command fork(). It creates a new instance that runs in the background. The main instance exists after that.

What would be the best option to check if the service is running? I'm considering:

- Create a file with the process id of the program and check if it's running with a script.
- Use `ps | grep` to find the program in the running proccess list.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems more like a question for http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ maybe...

Comment: It's common for daemon processes to write their PID to a file, such as /var/run/syslog.pid. If yours does that, your script can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better to manage your process with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), or other process control system.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job that runs every few minutes (or whatever you're comfortable with) and does something like this:

```
/path/to/is_script_stopped.sh && /path/to/script.sh
```

Write `is_script_stopped.sh` using any of the methods that you suggest. If your script is stopped cron will evaluate your script, if not, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

To the question, you gave in the headline:

This simple endless loop will restart yourProgram as soon as it fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((;;))
do
   yourProgram
done
```

If your program depends on a resource, which might fail, it would be wise to insert a short pause, to avoid, that it will catch all system resources when failing million times per second:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((;;))
do
   yourProgram
   sleep 1
done
```

To the question from the body of your post:

> What would be the best option to check if the service is running?

If your `ps` has a -C option (like the Linux ps) you would prefer that over a `ps ax | grep` combination.

```
 ps -C yourProgram
```